# unicorn fails to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, unicorn

I am trying to start a unicorn server. It was working fine before. Suddenly after a server restart, this error popped.

```
I, [2014-05-25T17:04:20.480271 #13922]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': No such file to load -- Token (LoadError)
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/releases/20140525165531/app/controllers/domains_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/quarterback/apps/quarterback-rails/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly one. I had a require 'Token' in one of my files.